# Driver's door beeps when open

Tags: electrical, door, barina

I have a 2003 Holden Barina, 5 door hatch, auto.

When I open the drivers side door, the car makes a ringing sound.

It *stops* ringing when either:

1. the key has been turned to on (II) position, and is fine when the car starts and is running

OR

2. the door is closed

or both.

Can anyone give me a general list of the most likely possible causes of the issue?

I've looked at fuses and read the owners manual which tells me that there is more than one type of noise for different things. According to the manual the noise I'm hearing is indicative of the headlights being left on, except that they are not.

Comment: The noise stops when the door is shut and/or the car is started and running.

Comment: Are the keys in the ignition? There are several different events which can cause the dinger to go off when the door is open ... have you checked the different cases to see if they are the cause?

Comment: Sorry. 

It will beep with keys in or out of the ignition, until the car is started.

I'm not at the car at the moment, I will double check as soon as I can and update the question with all the specifics.

From memory however it beeps until at least the ignition is turned on.

From what I understand in the owners manual it makes a different noise for 'keys left in the ignition' compared to 'headlights left on' and I believe it is the specific sound that indicates the headlights have been left on... Even though they haven't.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. I hope the edited question gives you some more information.

Can you clarify what you mean by cases?

Comment: Do you have access to wiring diagrams? Can you isolate where the ringing sound is coming from? I'm thinking if you can figure out what speaker/whatever is ringing you can work your way backwards. Though if it goes to a body control module you'll need a scan tool.

Comment: Sounds expensive. I have the Haynes manual, I could check it out.

I guess I was hoping it was a commonish/simplish problem that had a couple straightforwardish solutions.

My wife knows a good autolecky, that could be the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Had a mechanic out to service our Astra with same issue & he sorted it in about 2 seconds.  The build up of dirt in the ignition was causing it to stick making it think the key was still in the ignition.  A bit of WD40 and problem sorted...no more beep.